# aspnet_regsql in .net 3.5?

Tags: asp.net

I have ASP.net web site which compiled in .net 3.5 and looking for aspnet_regsql for 3.5.  And, I do not see the executable in the 3.5 folder but see it in 2.0.

Is that the latest?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx#findingthecorrectversion

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET 3.5 is an extension of .NET 2. So yes, the aspnet_regsql in the .NET 2.0 folder is the correct one to run.

Answer (score 0):

3.5 framework is depends on 2.0 framework so aspnet_regsql file you can find in 2.0 framework folder.